# How to set work group count appropriately in Vulkan

Tags: parallel-processing, gpgpu, vulkan

There used to be a parameter called `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` that can be queried in OpenCL by calling `clGetDeviceInfo`, which indicates the number of parallel compute units on the OpenCL device, as a single work-group executes on a single compute unit.

However there don't seem to be a way to query that parameter in Vulkan.

Or am I missing something, as in it can actually be queried? Or we usually choose a default value (such as 256) arbitrarily when the input size is indeterminate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vulkan has no way to ask that question. And that's probably for the best.

First, the concept of "compute unit" was not well defined even in OpenCL. So exactly what this value means is not well understood.

Second, if the question you really want to ask is "how many work groups can execute in parallel at any one time", then the answer may be shader-dependent. For example, if a piece of hardware can execute 32 work items on a single computation unit, it may be able to populate these 32 work items from *distinct* work groups. That is, your notion that "a single work-group executes on a single compute unit" is not necessarily true.

If a shader's work group size is 16, there's little to be lost by running them both at the same time. Sure, different barrier usage *may* cause them to get split up, but it may not. It's probably better to take the chance that it'll work than to assume it won't.

And third... what exactly do you intend to do with that information? If you have X work groups to execute, issuing multiple dispatch commands in groups of `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` isn't going to make this process go faster. And trying to interleave work groups from different compute tasks is going to be slower, due to having to reset pipelines or other state. It's better to through the whole work at the GPU and let its scheduler sort out how to apply the work items to the work groups.